# Regex to validate image urls with query string

Tags: regex, fluentvalidation

I want to validate image urls, few with query string and few without it.
https://images.company.com/img/800X450/vehicle/201610/858823_589_1475572549658.gif?bg=000000&wmi=n

http://images.company.com/img/800X450/vehicle/201610/858823_599_1475572549658.jpeg?bg=000000&wmi=n&pne=ur

http://images.company.com/img/800X450/vehicle/201610/858823_599_1475572549658.png

So basic thing is to validate any image with jpg|png|gif|jpeg extension, with or without query string parameter.

I tried using Matches(@".(?i)(jpg|png|gif|jpeg)") regex.

But problem is it is validating images like:
http://images.company.com/img/800X450/vehicle/201610/858823_599_1475572549658.pngg
OR
http://images.company.com/img/800X450/vehicle/201610/858823_599_1475572549658.giff

How can i validate if url has exact extension jpg or png or gif or jpeg and optionally some query string parameter after that?

Comment: Maybe something like this: `(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)((\?.*)$|$)` - the extension is either followed by a query string, or an end of string. [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/YrgpUf/3)

Comment: Actually i would even do like so: `(jpe?g|gif|png)(?=\?|$)` like here: https://regex101.com/r/bQDTiS/1

Comment: @antoni - for pure validation, that's a neat solution.  I guess the only risk is could validate an empty query string.

Comment: If you dont want to accept empty query string (which is not wrong itself) then you can just add `(jpe?g|gif|png)(?=\?.+|$)`

Answer (score 0):

Assert that the listed file extension must be followed by a query string or end of string:

```
(jpg|jpeg|gif|png)((\?+*)?$|$)
```

[HERE](https://regex101.com/r/YrgpUf/3)